# My code is executed after the end of the gulp task

Tags: gulp

I built an asyncronous gulp task to convert some sass files into css files and i got some troubles with timeline code execution.
I need to execute this task inside a loop and the code is executed after the end of the gulp task

```
  async build() {
        var self = this;
        var tasks = await this.themes.map(async(theme) => {

            return gulp.src(this.templatesPath + '/' + this.pattern)
            .pipe(header('@import \'' + this.themesPath + '/' + theme + '/' + this.themeFile + '\';'))
            .pipe(sass.sync().on('error', gutil.log))
            .pipe(rename(function (path: any) {
                var file = path.basename + path.extname;
                path.dirname += '/' + file;

                gutil.log(self.folders[theme][file]);
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(this.themesPath + '/' + theme))

            gutil.log('loop');

        });

        gutil.log('end');
    }
```

gutil.log output inside rename function is always outprinted after end of task

[18:08:34] Starting 'build'... 
[18:08:34] end 
[18:08:34] Finished 'build' after 33 ms 
[18:08:34] [ { '$': { 'jcr:primaryType': 'jnt:file' }, 
    'jcr:content': [ [Object] ] } ] 
[18:08:34] [ { '$': { 'jcr:primaryType': 'jnt:file' }, 
    'jcr:content': [ [Object] ] } ]

How can I handle the end of loop to be sure my objects are filled when i execute others tasks ?

Comment: Can you show the rest of your `gulpfile`?

If your other functions need the `build` function completed before they can be called, I think you have two options: 1. make the build function synchronous, or 2. call the `build` task from within your build process.

Why does the ` await this.themes.map(async(theme) => {` need to be assyncronous?

Comment: You're right, i found a synchronous solution using merge-stream to handle many tasks. I assign gulp tasks to tasks variable and I return all tasks which have been merged
`
var merge = require('merge-stream');
...
return merge(tasks);
`
Thanks for you help